# Javascript: how do I make the results from an autosuggest move into the input field when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosuggest

heres the code for the index file

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    Search: <input id="search" type="text"/>
    <div id="search_results">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

heres my search.js file this is where I need Help. I need help figuring out what values go into the '' marks. Ive tried putting 'search_results' and 'search' in every combination but it just wont work. Im new to jquery so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
var search_term = $(this).val();
$.post('php/search.php', { search_term: search_term }, function(data) {
    $('#search_results').html(data);

    $('').click(function(){
    var result_value = $(this).text();
    $('').val('', result_value);
    $('').html('');

    });
});
     });
```

Comment: how does the `data` looks like?

Comment: Please post your returned json/xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends upon how your result looks like. If you result contains something like this:

```
    <div id="search_results">
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>        
            <li>Option 2</li>        
            <li>Option 3</li>        
            <li>Option 4</li>        
            <li>Option 5</li>        
            <li>Option 6</li>        
        </ul>
    </div>​
```

Then you click handler would change to this:

```
    $('#search_results > ul > li').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            $('#search').val($(this).html());
        });            
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Srj5Z/